# Test results with trained LSTM model

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have 10,000 data for training of LSTM model. 10,000 dataset is extracted from database for the years before 2020. 60% of data is used for training, 20% for validation and 20% for test. Test data is never used in training and validation.
Then test results is 100%
Then the model is tested again with new similar data for the data after 2020.
The test accuracy is 31% only.
Why test accuracy is good but tested with new similar data is bad.